# Reading images from paths mentioned in a text file

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written the paths of a set of images into a text file..and i am trying to read the images successively in opencv. Then I need to find some feature from each image. But my method does not reading the images from the paths mentioned in the file. This is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{        
   FILE * fp;
   char * line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;

   fp = fopen("hmv.txt", "r");
   if (fp == NULL)
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
   {
      printf("%s",line);
      Mat image = imread(line);
      Ptr<FeatureDetector> featureDetector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
      vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
      featureDetector->detect(image, keypoints);
      Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> featureExtractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT");
      Mat descriptors;
      featureExtractor->compute(image, keypoints, descriptors);

      //Mat  MyMat=cvCreateMat(descriptors.rows,descriptors.cols,CV_64FC1);
      Mat output;
      reduce(descriptors,output,0,CV_REDUCE_SUM,CV_64FC1);
      string filename="feature.txt";
      FILE *file;
      file=fopen(filename,"wb");
      fwrite(&output,
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Please help, what is the flaw?

Comment: How does the error/problem manifest? Does your program fail to compile? If yes, please tell us more about the error message. If no, please be more specific about the expected results and what you actually get? How do you decide that there is a flaw in your program?

Answer (score 0):

from the getline manpage:

The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

so, you got a newline in the filename, imread won't like it ...